# Fullcalendar with resource view not working in ASP.NET MVC, on loading - 0x800a01bd - javaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Following is the code details, when I debugged its showing currentView is undefined when I initialize defaultView: 'resourceDay'

```
<html> 
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcal")

         <script type='text/javascript'>

             $(document).ready(function () {

                 var date = new Date();
                 var d = date.getDate();
                 var m = date.getMonth();
                 var y = date.getFullYear();

                 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                     header: {
                         left: 'prev,next today',
                         center: 'title',
                         right: 'resourceDay'
                     },
                     titleFormat: 'ddd, MMM dd, yyyy',
                     defaultView: 'resourceDay',
                     selectable: true,
                     selectHelper: true,
                     select: function (start, end, allDay, event, resourceId) {
                         var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                         if (title) {
                             console.log("@@ adding event " + title + ", start " + start + ", end " + end + ", allDay " + allDay + ", resource " + resourceId);
                             calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                             {
                                 title: title,
                                 start: start,
                                 end: end,
                                 allDay: allDay,
                                 resourceId: resourceId
                             },
                             true // make the event "stick"
                         );
                         }
                         calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                     },
                     eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta) {
                         console.log("@@ resize event " + event.title + ", start " + event.start + ", end " + event.end + ", resource " + event.resourceId);
                     },
                     eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay) {
                         console.log("@@ drag/drop event " + event.title + ", start " + event.start + ", end " + event.end + ", resource " + event.resourceId);
                     },
                     editable: true,
                     resources: [
                         {
                             name: 'Resource 1',
                             id: 'resource1'
                         },
                         {
                             name: 'Resource 2',
                             id: 'resource2'
                         },
                         {
                             name: 'Resource 3',
                             id: 'resource3'
                         }
                     ],
                     events: [
                         {
                             title: 'All Day Event 1',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d - 1),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d + 1),
                             resourceId: 'resource1'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'Short Event 1',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 30),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d, 13, 00),
                             allDay: false,
                             resourceId: 'resource1'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'Short Event 2',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 14, 00),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 15, 00),
                             allDay: false,
                             resourceId: 'resource1'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'All Day Event 2',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d - 1),
                             resourceId: 'resource2'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'Lunch',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                             allDay: false,
                             resourceId: 'resource2'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'All Day Event 3',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d),
                             resourceId: 'resource3'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'Click for Google',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d, 16, 0),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d, 16, 30),
                             allDay: false,
                             url: 'http://google.com/',
                             resourceId: 'resource3'
                         }
                     ]
                 });

             });

        </script>
 <style type='text/css'>

            body {
                margin-top: 40px;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            }

            #calendar {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)

                @RenderBody()


            <div id='calendar' style="border:dashed 2px red;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Following is the details on bundle

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        //"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js", 
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fullcal").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css",
                        "~/Content/fullcalendar.css",
                        "~/Content/fullcalendar.print.css"));
```

This resource works fine when its not using ASP.NET MVC
http://www.ikelin.com/jquery-fullcalendar-resource-day-view/

Can anyone please help me...

Comment: add  your script tag and all `@Script.Render`  code just before the </body>

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply still its showing the error                                              </body>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcal")

    followed by the script tag for fullcalendar

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until `DOM` finishes loading. Then you can apply your scripts. Since, in your master page, it is always a best practice to put all your scripts at bottom rather than at the header since the parser uses top down approach, it executes the script, after the body is completed loading.

add  your script tag and all `@Script.Render`  code just before the `</body>`

and first add all the `@Script.Render`  and then the `<script></script>` tag like

```
<body>

       <div id='calendar' style="border:dashed 2px red;"></div>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcal")

         <script type='text/javascript'>

             $(document).ready(function () {

                 var date = new Date();
                 var d = date.getDate();
                 var m = date.getMonth();
                 var y = date.getFullYear();

                 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                     header: {
                         left: 'prev,next today',
                         center: 'title',
                         right: 'resourceDay'
                     },
                     titleFormat: 'ddd, MMM dd, yyyy',
                     defaultView: 'resourceDay',
                     selectable: true,
                     selectHelper: true,
                     select: function (start, end, allDay, event, resourceId) {
                         var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                         if (title) {
                             console.log("@@ adding event " + title + ", start " + start + ", end " + end + ", allDay " + allDay + ", resource " + resourceId);
                             calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                             {
                                 title: title,
                                 start: start,
                                 end: end,
                                 allDay: allDay,
                                 resourceId: resourceId
                             },
                             true // make the event "stick"
                         );
                         }
                         calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                     },
                     eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta) {
                         console.log("@@ resize event " + event.title + ", start " + event.start + ", end " + event.end + ", resource " + event.resourceId);
                     },
                     eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay) {
                         console.log("@@ drag/drop event " + event.title + ", start " + event.start + ", end " + event.end + ", resource " + event.resourceId);
                     },
                     editable: true,
                     resources: [
                         {
                             name: 'Resource 1',
                             id: 'resource1'
                         },
                         {
                             name: 'Resource 2',
                             id: 'resource2'
                         },
                         {
                             name: 'Resource 3',
                             id: 'resource3'
                         }
                     ],
                     events: [
                         {
                             title: 'All Day Event 1',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d - 1),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d + 1),
                             resourceId: 'resource1'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'Short Event 1',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 30),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d, 13, 00),
                             allDay: false,
                             resourceId: 'resource1'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'Short Event 2',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 14, 00),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 15, 00),
                             allDay: false,
                             resourceId: 'resource1'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'All Day Event 2',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d - 1),
                             resourceId: 'resource2'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'Lunch',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                             allDay: false,
                             resourceId: 'resource2'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'All Day Event 3',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d),
                             resourceId: 'resource3'
                         },
                         {
                             title: 'Click for Google',
                             start: new Date(y, m, d, 16, 0),
                             end: new Date(y, m, d, 16, 30),
                             allDay: false,
                             url: 'http://google.com/',
                             resourceId: 'resource3'
                         }
                     ]
                 });

             });

        </script>
</body>
```

Then it should solve the problem. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, still its showing the error

Comment: Unhandled exception at line 357, column 3 in http://localhost:12617/Scripts/fullcalendar.js

0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action

Comment: I added like this  `</body>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcal")
         <script type='text/javascript'>

             $(document).ready(function () {

                 var date = new Date();
                 var d = date.getDate();
                 var m = date.getMonth();
                 var y = date.getFullYear();

                 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
:
:

});

 </script>
</html>`

Comment: @IronBridge which version of full calender you are using 2.2.5 ?

Comment: FullCalendar version 1.6.4

Comment: Stills its showing the same error I have a @RenderSession inside the body      '<div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)

                @RenderBody()
        </div'

Comment: create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code make sure you added reference to all the dependent scripts

Answer (score 0):

I found out from this link: [https://forums.asp.net/t/1928230.aspx?0x800a01b6+Microsoft+JScript+runtime+error+Object+doesn+t+support+property+or+method+live+run+time+error+help+please+](https://forums.asp.net/t/1928230.aspx?0x800a01b6%20Microsoft%20JScript%20runtime%20error%20Object%20doesn%20t%20support%20property%20or%20method%20live%20run%20time%20error%20help%20please%20) that if you remove the following piece of code it will work: "@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")". Hope it helps.